# How to create an image by giving the specifications

Tags: android, image

I want to create an image (e.g coupons) in my applications by giving the specifications in the edit text.Let suppose i have 3 edit texts for name,color,content respectively.when i fill these details and click on submit button, A image should generate containing all the specifications that i have giving in the edit text so that user can change it any time and generate the desired image.

how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

You can create a Bitmap of whatever size you want for your coupons:

```
Bitmap coupon = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

Then you create a Canvas for drawing into the Bitmap:

```
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(coupon);
```

Draw your coupon using `canvas` with the same calls as you would when drawing to the screen. Finally, you can display the Bitmap on the screen either in a custom view's `onDraw` method or by creating an ImageView and calling it's `setImageBitmap` method with your coupon bitmap.